# Python: How to store an array in Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a project where I process a URL and get an array (containing columns and rows) using beautifulsoup. Now I need to store this data in the datastore. I cannot find any reference on storing an array in the datastore.

Answer (score 13):

A multivalued property is represented in the datastore api as a python list. If you can organize the data in list, you can define a part of your data model as

```
class MyData(ndb.Model):
    array = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

In the request handler, store the data like

```
data = MyData()
data.array = list_you_got_from_request
data.put()
```

Comment: Use `ndb`. The property would be is `ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)` and we subclass from `ndb.Model` instead. All other code is the same.

Comment: @bossylobster That's a good suggestion. Edited the code to use ndb instead of db.